# linux shell - can't compare strings with: adb shell getprop ro.product.brand

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

This is really odd...
I can't get this test to result in true in my linux shell and I can't figure out why.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(adb shell getprop ro.product.brand)
adb shell getprop ro.product.brand
if [ "$a" == "Huawei" ]; then
echo "Success"
else
echo "Failed"
fi
```

The script just outputs:

```
Huawei
Failed
```

Whereas this script:

```
b=$(whoami)
whoami
if [ "$b" == "amo" ]; then
echo "Success"
else
echo "Failed"
fi
```

...outputs:

```
amo
Success
```

Can anyone help me understand that?

I already tried cutting away spaces or line breaks in $a  by piping to cut or sed but I get the same result...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the string contains no trailing whitespace or newline?  It seems like the likely problem in such a case...

Comment: I think so. See the post below.

Comment: Try this : `echo "${#a}`.  This will print the number of characters in the value of the variable, so you can validate that there is nothing foul going on (such as a non-printable character not shown but taken into account when comparing the strings).

Comment: There is indeed something wrong here: The number of characters is 7, though "Huawei" is only 6 - even after using the trim function from the post below.

Comment: Interestingly, if I just execute `$a`, I get the message: `./test.sh: line 21: $'Huawei\r': command not found`

Comment: You found your problem.  Please look at my answer below, and try it with `[[:space:]]` replacing `[[:blank:]]` everywhere in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this as a way to remove leading/trailing whitespace :

```
# Trims $1
# If $2 supplied, assigns result to variable named $2
# If $2 not present, echoes the value to stdout
trim()
{
  if
    [[ $1 =~ ^[[:blank:]]*(.*[^[:blank:]])[[:blank:]]*$ ]]
  then
    local result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  else
    local result="$1"
  fi
  if
    (( $# > 1 ))
  then
    printf -v "$2" %s "$result"
  else
    printf %s "$result"
  fi
}
```

This function uses no external program, so has low overhead.

Maybe a quick explanation of the regular expression...

```
^[[:blank:]]*(.*[^[:blank:]])[[:blank:]]*$
```

- It matches all leading and trailing whitespace (no surprise there)
- In the middle, it matches any string of characters that ends with a non-blank and saves that as a sub-expression for access with `BASH_REMATCH`
- If there were no "non-blank" character specified to end the middle portion, the greedy `.*` would eat everything up until the end of the string, including trailing blanks.
- The `.*` is, on the other hand, certain to begin with a non-blank, because the greedy initial `[[:blank:]]*` will only stop when encountering a non-blank.

Depending on your need, you may also use `[[:space:]]` instead of `[[:blank:]]` (difference explained here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes).  Basically, `[[:blank:]]` matches tabs and spaces, and `[[:space:]]` also matches newlines, carriage returns, and a few more.

Comment: Hey thank you, I indeed needed to use `[[:space:]]` instead of `[[:blank:]]`. That works!